# What is the advantage of making a "String-Based" API like getSystemService()?

Tags: java, android, oop, api-design

I'm kind of new to Android programming, and i'm comming from a strong background of iOS programming.

I noticed a "weird" thing in the Android platform:
Some System-Services (like `NotificationManager`) are accessed through the method `getSystemService()` which accepts a string as a parameter and returns the desired class.

My question is, why did Google (or whoever designed this API) made it this way and did not make specific get method for each system service?

I think that making a separate method for each service is more robust and less error-prone. It also saves the need of casting, which is kind of "ugly" programming.

So what is the advantage of using retriving-by-name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was done for abstract generality and the ability to add more as needed with next versions without disrupting the schema with new method names, parameters, etc.

Comment: How does it achieve either of those goals more than normal API usage?

Comment: @luxun: I don't know much about the Android API, but usually a string-based key lookup is useful for when the values are add dynamically, or "on the fly".

Comment: @Jeremy: This is definetly not the case here, since those are system services. They do not change dynamically.

Comment: @Avrahamshuk No idea about android, but it seems this way they can support new versions with the same interface, ie without having to link different jars or call different methods (just a different string) for several different versions (ie same code for android 1.0 through 3.1). Could be wrong though :)